# jQuery change event alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

it would be great if anyone could suggest an alternative to 'change' event in jQuery?

I tried with `focusout` but that only works after I click on the page and the targeted event is triggered. What I want is when I enter a text in the field, it should work similar to how change works.

Comment: Whats wrong with `change` event? Why can't you simply use it.

Comment: Alternative to `change` for what input element type?

Comment: @Satpal — `change` won't fire until the focus is lost.

Comment: @Satpal: I have some constraints thus needed an alternative.

Comment: @david: for textfield

Comment: And what constraints do you have? Please, take some time to compose a question that includes the relevant detail.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment that its **textfield** and you have written **'when I enter a text in the field, it should work similar to how change works'**

Use `.keyup()` event as shown.

```
$("#txt").on('keyup',function(){
 ....
});
```

or use `.input()` as shown:

```
$("#txt").on('input',function(){
 ....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) event. That should fire when the input is changed for any reason (typing, pasting, etc).

Comment: Thanks @quentin, I'll try and will let you know if that worked for me.